# Find $\int \frac{\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+3 \sin (2x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+3 \sin (2x)}dx $$.
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1/t}-\sqrt{t}}{(1+t^2+6t)}dt $$
I use $\sin(2x)=2\tan(x)/(1+\tan^2(x))$ in denominator.I can convert everything in terms of $\tan(x)$ but then I'm not able to manipulate the square root of tan which still remains in numerator.What next?

Comment: I used that only.Please read the question before commenting.How do I manage the the square root that persists after the substitution? @You'reInMyEye

Comment: Was the trouble with the substitution or after the substitution?

Comment: @Mike after the substitution....

Comment: @You'reInMyEye It's quite easily visible what happens after the substitution so I don't think its necessary to write each and every step.If you don't want to help its your choice.

Comment: @MathJack, so you can't be bothered to write your question properly, and expect others to answer you? I'm sure some would, but not me

Comment: Ok I get your point. @You'reInMyEye

Comment: @You'reInMyEye done!Happy now? :-)

Comment: :-(.No.I don't know what to do with the square root. @You'reInMyEye

Comment: @MathJack, how did you get the edited version?

Comment: @MathJack, your edit is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I = \frac{\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+3\sin 2x}dx = \int\frac{\cot x-\tan x}{\left(\sqrt{\cot x}+\sqrt{\tan x}\right)(1+3\sin 2x)}dx$$

So $$I = \int\frac{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}}{\sin x\cos x(\cos x+\sin x)(1+3\sin 2x)}dx$$

So $$I = \sqrt{2}\int\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)}{(1+3\sin 2x)\sqrt{\sin 2x}}dx$$

Now Put $\sin x+\cos x = t\Rightarrow t^2-1=\sin 2x$ and $(\cos x-\sin x)dx = dt$

So $$I = \int\frac{1}{(1+3t^2-3)\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt = \int\frac{1}{(3t^2-2)\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$$

Now Put $\displaystyle t= \frac{1}{u}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dt=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$

So $$I = -\int\frac{u}{(3-2u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

Now Put $(1-u^2) = v^2\;,$ Then $-udu = vdv$

So $$I = \int\frac{1}{3-2(1-v^2)}dv = \int\frac{1}{1+2v^2}dv$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{v^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}dv = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}v\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2t^2-2}}{t}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(\sin x+\cos x)^2-2}}{\sin x+\cos x}\right)+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\sin 2x}}{\sin x+\cos x}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: This is nice, but you are helping someone who has shown no effort. At least now the OP can't delete the question

Comment: Yes You're In My Eye , You are saying Right, May be OP can motivated from our answers, and next time If he post his/her solution, I am sure that He will make some efforts., Thanks

Comment: Was this sarcasm? Anyway, great solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I = \int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+3\sin 2x}dx = \int\frac{1-\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan x}\cdot \left(1+3\cdot 2 \frac{\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}\right)}dx$$

Now Put $\tan x= t^2\;,$ Then $\sec^2 xdx = 2tdt$

So $$I = 2\int\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^4+6t^2)}dt  = -2\int\frac{1-\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+6}dt$$

So $$I = -2\int\frac{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{'}}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+2^2}dt = -\frac{2}{2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right]+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = -\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}}{2}\right)+\mathcal{C} = \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}}{2}\right)+\mathcal{C'} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. An obvious one

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1/t}-\sqrt{t}}{(1+3 \frac{2t}{1-t^2})(1+t^2)}dt=\int\frac{(1-t)(1-t^2)}{\sqrt{t}(1-t^2+6t)(1+t^2)}dt=^{\sqrt{t}=u} \\ =2 \int\frac{(1-u^2)(1-u^4)}{(1-u^4+6u^2)(1+u^4)}du$$